# Handlerbars for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, handlebars.js

While I am quite new to the Apple developing stuff, coming from a long front-end dev career, I'm wondering if there's any better option than just using a function like `refreshUI` when I receive data from server.

I'm used to stuff like RactiveJS, Angular ( stuff based on handlebars which updates automatically in the interface when giving it a new value )

Any ideas or knowledge about that ?
I could be stupid or maybe I don't know what to exactly search for on google.

Comment: there are many to refreshUI in iOS. In iOS there will be views and subviews, if you want to update them you need to call setNeedsDisplay!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using Swift, SwiftBond is where it's at
https://github.com/SwiftBond/Bond

Comment: After reading the documentations from the other libraries, this just seems more... similar to what I was doing before

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are in luck!

By far the most common and well supported library for this in iOS is Reactive Cocoa:

https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa

The learning curve may be a bit steep but its well worth it in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatives to explore:

- Reactive Cocoa
- RxSwift
- DIY via a combination of
  -- Key value observing
  -- UINotificationCenter
  -- MVVM design patterns
  -- Closures

Don't take the above as exhausting, I am in the process of figuring out myself the best course of action.